# Why is a firestore listener returning .added twice when a single document is added?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using google maps and my users can add a map marker to the map. 
The map markers are stored in firestore.
I have a listener that listens in to the database.
Each user can only submit one map marker - so there is only one document for each user in the database. But they can modify the lat and lng of their marker.

My firestore is set out as:

```
root
  - submittedMarkers (collection)
          - fireauthID_1 (document)
                - field 1 (lat): 
                - field 2 (lng):
          - fireauthID_2 (document)
                - field 1 (lat):
                - field 2 (lng):
```

// MapController.swift

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    listener = db.collection("submittedMarkers").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in   
            if (diff.type == .added){
                print("added")
            }
            if(diff.type == .modified) {
                print("modified the document in firestore")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment for debugging I only have one user in firestore and one document under `submittedMarkers` -> `{fireauthId}`.

When my app loads the single marker that currently exists is added to the map along with a single print statement "added". So that works.

Here is the problem I've encountered.

When a new user registers and gets a fireauth id they can then go and add a marker from the `AddMarkerController`. When they submit the marker i use an unwind segue to get them back to the `MapController`. (I don't detach the listener at any stage from the `MapController`).

// AddMarkerController

```
docref = db.collection("submittedMarkers").document(currentUserId)
docref?.setData([
    "latitude": latitude,
    "longitude": longitude,
    "date_time": date!,
    "distance": dist, 
    "speed": speed
], options: SetOptions.merge()) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error writing document: \(err)")
    } else {

    }
}
```

But what I have found is that when they have come back to the `MapController` the `if (diff.type == .added)` is executed twice and print("added") happens twice even though the currentuser fireauth id is added just the once under the collection `submittedMarkers`.

And when I print out the `diff.document.ID` i'm getting both the fireauth id of the user who was already in firestore and the current user who just added a new document.

I suspect I don't quite get then how the listener works. I thought `if(diff = .added)` would listen to the `submittedMarkers` collection and only fire once when a new document is added.

I wasn't sure if the issue is:

1. I don't detach the listener when I leave the `MapController` -> `AddMarkerController`?
2. The listener is in `viewWillAppear` and not `viewDidLoad` but from reading the firebase blog it should be in `viewWillAppear`
3. Whether it's the `snapshot.documentChanges.forEach` which is looping through the entire snapshot each time something changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `added` is the local event that is fired as soon as you call `setData()`. The second `added` is the acknowledged event after the server has written the data.

See the [events for local changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes) section in the documentation.

Another reason might be that you fail to unregister your observer. If you register your observer in `viewWillAppear`, unregister it in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` . If you don't, you'll end up with multiple observers for the same event and thus with multiple invocations.

Comment: Hi @Frank. I'm still getting the same behaviour. I logged into my app as a second user. The single marker in firestore is loaded appropriately and diff = .added is triggered once. But then everytime I go from the MapController to another controller and come back, viewWillAppear executes as always but I find myself back in diff == .added with the Server data loading again every time. I have put an update at the end of the original post with more info. I wonder if my listener is re-registering each time i come back to viewWillAppear. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, that could be. I must admit I didn't read *all* the code + description in your question (in general: less is more). If you register your observer in `viewWillAppear`, unregister it in `ViewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear `. If you don't, you'll end up with multiple observers for the same event and thus with multiple invocations.