# The SnapShotListener is trying to remove a document when I am adding a new document the second time around

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm still relatively a noob and I'm having a bit of a hard time figuring out this bug.

I'm working on a gym logging app that is quite basic and consists of two TableViewControllers inside of a NavigationStack. I'm using Firebase/Firestore as my backend and I have snapShotListeners setup for each viewController for when new data is added or removed.

The bug I'm running into is a bit hard to explain, but I'll try my best...

- First, I create two new documents in my `firstTableViewController` named "A" and "B" and then within each of those documents I create another two documents in my `secondViewController` named "C" and "D".
- Next, I delete documents "A" and "B" in my `firstTableViewController`, which also deletes the two pairs of documents "C" and "D" automatically. All these changes are observed and reflected on the Firestore backend, so no problems, everything works the way it's supposed to work.
- At this point I'm back at square one with two empty `TableViewControllers`. So now I try to do the exact same thing that I just did by re-creating the two documents that I created earlier, with the exact same names "A" and "B", and I also attempt to re-create documents "C" and "D" within "A" and within "B" respectively. However this time, when I try to re-create document "D" within document "B", my `diff.type == .removed` gets executed within my `snapShotListener` on my `secondViewController` for some reason, and I get the `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` code...

I have no idea why this happens and it's breaking my head. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Again, I'm quite new to this, so my debugging skills are not quite to par just yet. I'd be happy to include code, but I'm not exactly sure of how much code I should reveal...please let me know.

Thank you in advanced!

EDIT:

If I only have two documents ("C" and "D") in my `SecondViewController`, when I enter that VC, my `diff.type == .added` get's executed 4 times instead of 2. It prints "Document Added" 4 times even though there are only 2 documents in that collection. Here is the code...

```
//MARK: - Load the Data
    func loadExercises() {

        feedback = self.exerciseCollection!.whereField("Workout", isEqualTo: selectedWorkout!.workout).order(by: "Timestamp", descending: false).addSnapshotListener({ (querySnapshot, err) in

            let group = DispatchGroup()

            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {return}

            snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
                
                if (diff.type == .added) {
                    self.exerciseArray.removeAll()

                    group.enter()
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                        let workoutData = document.data()
                        let exercise = workoutData["Exercise"] as! String

                        let newExercise = Exercise(Day: self.selectedWorkout!.day, Workout: self.selectedWorkout!.workout, Exercise: exercise, Key: document.reference)
                        self.exerciseArray.append(newExercise)
                        print("Document Added")
                    }
                    group.leave()
                    group.notify(queue: .main){
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                
                if (diff.type == .removed) {
                     print("Document Removed")

                     self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [self.indexToRemove!], with: .automatic)
                }
            }

            }
        )}
```

Comment: Hey Gary, is that error coming from firebase SDK itself or from somewhere in your own code? Also, FYI firebase listens to a PATH that you provide, so even if there is no document yet on that path, your controllers are already subscribed.

Comment: Hi Taier, I'm getting the error within my own code, pointing to this line...
`self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [self.indexToRemove!], with: .automatic)`

Comment: I'm not sure why it's executing .removed when I'm clearly adding...

Comment: thanks, yeap that is a strange behavior... I would advise you to listen for other events added/modified to see if they are triggered before .removed

Comment: I think I found some light, removed: Indicates a document within the query was removed (either deleted or no longer matches the query.https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Enums/DocumentChangeType#removed

Comment: Gary, here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47764065/2199894

Comment: I do have code that removes the listeners in my viewWillDissapear(). So I guess that part doesn't have anything to do with the bug. Thanks though.

Comment: What's the Dispatch group for in this case? Also, diff will contains the differences so it could be .added, .modified and .removed with removed meaning the object no longer fits the criteria of the where.

Comment: I suppose that I don't need the Dispatch Group now that you mention it.